# Bash: using both way redirections in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, gzip

I'm writing a shell script to compress and backup certain files. This will compress and move large files with sizes up to 4 GB.

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
    gzip < $filelocation > $backuplocation
```

Where

```
  $filelocation = /home/user/image.img 

  $backuplocation = /home
```

And I will add a similar line to decompress the file

```
    gunzip < $filelocation > $backuplocation
```

Now it doesn't work for some reason.

I try
        gunzip $filelocation > $backuplocation

Will I be able to pipe it and move the compressed file instead into the directory?

Comment: What you've written is plausible, but knowing what `$filelocation` and `$backuplocation` are might help. What error message do you get? What _exactly_ do you mean by "it doesn't work for some reason"?

Comment: Well, I have an if statement to check if $backuplocation is a directory. And if it is, compress the file and dump it into that directory. The error I'm getting is `code./backup.sh: line 28: /home: Is a directory`. Check my edit to see the paths specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't make a backup with `gzip` into a directory, but into a different file:

```
 gzip < file.in > file.out
```

or in your case:

```
 filelocation=/home/user/image.img
 backuplocation=/home/image.img.gz
 gzip < "$filelocation" > "$backuplocation"
```

based on that you can do:

```
 gunzip < "$backuplocation" > /some/new/location/image.img
```

Comment: `"$backuplocation"`, surely?

Comment: @roaima yes, should have done copy and paste

Comment: I run the above with bash -x to see the process and it gets stuck on gzip command. it just shows ` + gzip` which should be followed by the paths but apparently it's not working. No error msg either. the line in question: `gzip < "$filedir/$filename" > "$dirpath/$filename"
` [I'm asking for directory and file name this time so I can use the file name when specifying the backup. Should it be `"$dirpath/$filename.gz"` instead?

Comment: @BruceStrafford the output name is not required to have the `.gz`  extension, it is just custom, and what you get if you do `gzip somefile` (without redirection, the result is `somefile.gz`) gzip can take a while, use `gzip -vv` to see some progress.

Comment: @Anthon It worked! Marked as the answer.